# Xamarin Experiment - SetFlags - AppTheme_Experimental

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have decided to update a Xamarin Forms app to XF 4.8.  I have written some AppThemeColor for the handling of dark mode.  Everything worked fine in XF 4.6.  Upgrading to XF 4.8 has produced an error now where I am getting the error that AppThemeColor does not exist and wondering if I have referenced all of my assemblies.  Previously, there had been a problem with the the XF 4.7 and needing to opt into the experimental theme features.  Ok, so I go into my App.xaml.cs class and into the App initializor and call:

```
Device.SetFlags(new string[] {"AppTheme_Experimental"});
```

No love.  Ok, so I try this in the iOS and Android projects to set the flags programmatically in the FinishedLaunching and the OnCreate methods.  Still no love.  I continue to get the errors.

Personally, I would think that I need to do something in a project options setting to get the compiler to pick this up, but I don't see anything.

Question: How do I turn on the AppThemeColor so that it will compile properly?

TIA,
Wally

Answer (score 0):

You could use `AppThemeBinding` to handling of dark mode.

```
 <!-- Light colors -->
    <Color x:Key="LightPrimaryColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
    <Color x:Key="LightSecondaryColor">Black</Color>

    <!-- Dark colors -->
    <Color x:Key="DarkPrimaryColor">Teal</Color>
    <Color x:Key="DarkSecondaryColor">White</Color>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle"
           TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightPrimaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkPrimaryColor}}" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor"
                Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightSecondaryColor}, Dark={StaticResource DarkSecondaryColor}}" />
    </Style>
```

I test on Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1269. It works well when i add the code below in `MainActivity` before `Forms.Init()`.

```
Forms.SetFlags("AppTheme_Experimental");
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        
        LoadApplication(new App());
```

You could download the source file from the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-systemthemesdemo/